# Notepad++ Filter by Content

Tags: notepad++

I have several text files with different titles and I need:

1 - filter only files whose content contains "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-9xjaJAaks";

2 - in the filtered files replace all occurrences of "2001" for "2000"

obs.: all files are .doc type and both 2001 and 2000 occur in the content of all files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. Your title references Notepad++ but you say all your files are text files that are of .doc type. Are you attempting to filter a list of file names within a document or do you want to filter out files on your filesystem to then do something with them. More details are needed to clearly define your problem and desired solution. Also, show us how things are currently set up (examples!!) and what work you have done thus far to solve your problem.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++

Comment: As Toto said, I suspect this isn't really a job for Notepad++, but I'm not currently allowed to use things with batch commands.

Comment: Brian, they are files in folders and their titles are not the focus of the filter, but the content, that is, only the DOC where the quoted url is transcribed in the content. As I am limited to Notepad++, I looked for a way to fill the "filters" field with some wildcard internal to the DOCs content, but the filters seem limited to file titles. My attempts so far have been filters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-9xjaJAaks* *,doc and filters: *g-9xjaJAaks *.doc

Comment: Are you looking to [Use Notepad++ to find text in all files of a folder](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/09/16/use-notepad-to-find-text-in-all-files-of-a-folder/)? I don't know how well this will work on `.doc` files, but you can try.

Comment: Notepad can technically use regex capture groups to capture an entire file's contents and replace specific things, but it's complex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392392/replace-regexp-capture-group-in-notepad. It might be easier to try: **1)** Find in files: `g-9xjaJAaks` **2)** in the search results, right click > "Find in these search results" > `2001` **3)** copy the result paths and find/replace one by one